# Can't seem to get my Java to work in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to get VS Code to work and compile my Java code. I have finally given up trying to fix it myself.

I can't compile my code, I can't run it. I don't even know what's wrong with it. I really want to use VS Code because it's so clean and versatile (so please don't recommend me other IDEs).

Here is my code:

```
class DataStruct {
    Run|Debug
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

<sup>(Manually transcribed from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WwAS.png).)</sup>

Here are my system variables:

[image: System Variables]

This is what I get:

```
PS C:\Users\SvenH\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\java-ws> cd "c:\Users\SvenH\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\java-ws\" ; if ($?) { javac DataStruct.java } ; if ($?) { java DataStruct }
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: DataStruct has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
PS C:\Users\SvenH\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\java-ws>
```

Comment: what did you see when you type in `java -version` and `javac -version` commands in `cmd`...?

Comment: "Java -version" gives me: java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)                
                                                                                                                             
         -|||||||||||||||||||- and javac -version gives me: javac 11.0.3

Comment: and what `javac -version` displays...

Comment: I edited it in. Pressed enter and it posted :(

Comment: Remove jre path from environment variable and try `java -version`

Comment: Okay did that. And got java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: It looks like the key error is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: DataStruct has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`. Is `DataStruct` a class that you have written?

Comment: Are the references to Visual Studio Code relevant? In other words, do these errors only happen when you call javac though the editor but not elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are compiling and using the same java version.
One simple way to do it is:

- uninstall JDK and JRE
- download JDK and JRE, both at the same version
- install them

Comment: You don't really need JRE if you have JDK, do you?

Comment: I just proposed an answer based on the op machine configurations. But you are correct indeed